# Chainlink VRF: Calling s_randomWords array shows execution reverted in Remix

Tags: remix, chainlink, vrf, goerli

Hi I am using the demo contract provided by `chainlink` at https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/examples/get-a-random-number/ . I did read the documentaion and followed the steps -

- Created subscription and then deployed the contract with that `subscriptionId`
- Funded the subscription with 0.5 `LINK`
- Added the address of the deployed contract as consumer in my subscription

When I call the `requestRandomWords` the transaction goes through successfully and but when I try to get the requested random number by `s_randomWords` with index 0 `remix` show `execution reverted`.

[image]

I am working on mumbai testnet and I have sufficient test `matic` so that is not the issue, when I try on `goerli` it shows `execution reverted`.

Just `s_randomWords` is not working upon calling and `requestRandomWords` works with transaction successful showing on `etherscan`, I have worked with `chainlink VRF` before and have seen this error before, please help me resolve this issue, Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by getting random number by s_randomWords with index 0? Isn't the fulfillRandomWords function the only way for the consumer contract to get the result random words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution reverted because `s_randomWords` is an empty array since the fulfillment of the request hasn't been executed yet. You have a pending transaction due to a low balance. Pending requests will fail after 24 hours.

Currently, the maximum cost for a VRF request on Goerli is 2.0575084648217579 LINK, which means you're 1.5575084648217579 LINK low. You can see these details on the Subscription management page at `vrf.chain.link/goerli/<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>` (make sure your wallet is connected)

You should add more Goerli LINK to your subscription. You can grab them for free from [faucets.chain.link](https://faucets.chain.link).

Comment: Thanks, it was not clearly mentioned.